# Boghe for wp8 send

Tags: windows-phone-8

I had a problem:

```
        SipCallback callback = new SipCallback();
        MySipStack mSipStack = new MySipStack(callback, realm, impi, impu);

        MyMessagingSession shortMessageSession = new MyMessagingSession(mSipStack,                 this.remotePartyUri);
        shortMessageSession.SendTextMessage(this.msgtextbox.Text);
        shortMessageSession.Dispose();
```

As described above,i can't send messages and I got the following error:

```
file: "..\..\..\..\..\..\doubango\branches\2.0\doubango\tinyNET\src\tnet_utils.c" 
line: "357" 
MSG: Not implemented on your OS
***ERROR: function: "tsip_api_message_send_message()" 
file: "..\..\..\..\..\..\doubango\branches\2.0\doubango\tinySIP\src\api\tsip_api_message.c" 
line: "69" 
MSG: Stack not started.
*INFO: *** SIP Session destroyed ***
```

How to successfully send a message？

regards

Comment: Some people experience this problem?